# Is it possible to install kdiff3 in aws ubuntu instance?

Tags: git, git-config

I configured git merge tool as below command

```
git config --global merge.tool kdiff3
```

I am getting below error message

```
The merge tool kdiff3 is not available as 'kdiff3'
```

Comment: It is Ubuntu. If you can establish an SSH session to the server just install it like any other application or package. Does `sudo apt install kdiff3` not work?

Comment: Thanks @GregBurghardt, I misunderstood it is installed by default in AWS instance. Now  i have installed the tool. And exploring further. :)

Comment: @GregBurghardt, I am accessing my linux box (aws instance) in putty. The kdiff3 tool is not coming up as UI. It just stops with question, Merge conflict is there for sure.  ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-33:~/SampleGit/Branch1$ git mergetool
Merging:
Branch1Master.txt

Normal merge conflict for 'Branch1Master.txt':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Branch1Master.txt seems unchanged.
Was the merge successful [y/n]? n
merge of Branch1Master.txt failed
Continue merging other unresolved paths [y/n]? y
ubuntu@ip-172-31-26-33:~/SampleGit/Branch1$

Comment: That is a different problem. Actually, it's not a problem at all. It just means the auto merge of the file did not make it appear as if the file had changed at all. This isn't necessarily a bad thing. Open the file. If it looks good, reply `y` to the prompt on the command line and move on.

Comment: Thanks @GregBurghardt. It worked out.